# Setting level to a logger in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

In `logback-spring.xml` file of a project that is new to me I see this configuration

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
 ......
 </appender>
 <logger name="com.myproject.myclass" level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
 </logger>
```

As far as I understand, all logs from `com.myproject.myclass` class will be sent to `<appender name="STDOUT">` that is console.

Could someone explain me what will be the level of this log with this config `level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}"`? In documentation I see only constants like `WARN`, `DEBUG`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring `${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}` means APP_LOGGING_LEVEL is a dynamic variable. The value for which can be set from properties file or from command line when running the project or from any other place accessible. If not set whatever after `:` is selected.
 In your case if not set `INFO` is selected